# PHP Filter non-usa Visitors

Tags: php, filter, ip-address, geo

Anyone have a solution, preferably free, to be able to take anyone hitting the site from a non-usa IP address and send them to a page saying "For US visitors only"?

Answer (score 1):

See this [tutorial](http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/469/how-to-make-an-ip-to-country-tool-with-php-and-mysql). You can filter non-US IPs with the codes in tutorial. It requires PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need a database of IP addresses.
http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country
Something like this should do it